# dplyr join on column A OR column B

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I join 2 tables with an OR statement in R using dplyrs join functions?

E.g. Join df1 on df2 with the key:
df1_ColumnA == df2_ColumnA OR df1_ColumnA == df2_ColumnB?

```
library(dplyr)

df1 = data.frame(V1 = c('A', 'B', 'C','D'), v2 = c(1,2,3,4))
df2 = data.frame(VA = c('A', 'B', 'C'), VB = c('D', 'E', 'F'), vC = c(4,5,6))

## Join on column 1
df3 = df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = c('V1' = 'VA'))

## join on column 1 AND column 2
df4 = df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = c('V1' = 'VA', 'V1' = 'VB'))
```

This is not working:

```
## join on column 1 OR column 2
df4 = df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = c('V1' = 'VA' | 'V1' = 'VB'))
```

**Edit: expected output**

```
   V1 v2 VA VB vC
1  A  1  A  D  4
2  B  2  B  E  5
3  C  3  C  F  6
4  D  4  A  D  4
```

Comment: That will not work.  Can you how the expectedd output.  You can do two joins and then reduce `map(c("VA", "VB"), ~ df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = c('V1' = .x)))`, but it depends on your expected output

Comment: It is possible that you need a full_join, `df1 %>% full_join(df2, by = c('V1' = 'VA', 'V1' = 'VB'))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `OR` join is not implemented in `tidyverse` (could be wrong too).  But, there is one option to `unite` the columns of interest together andd then do a `regex_right_join/regex_left_join` from `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
    unite(VAB, VA, VB, remove = FALSE) %>%
    regex_right_join(df1, by = c("VAB" = "V1")) %>% 
    select(names(df1), names(df2))
#.  V1 v2 VA VB vC
#1  A  1  A  D  4
#2  B  2  B  E  5
#3  C  3  C  F  6
#4  D  4  A  D  4
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `sqldf`

```
sqldf::sqldf('select a.*,b.* from df1 a left join df2 b on a.V1=b.VA or a.V1=b.VB')

   V1 v2 VA VB vC
1  A  1  A  D  4
2  B  2  B  E  5
3  C  3  C  F  6
4  D  4  A  D  4
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I would do if I would use SQL. I am curious if there would also be a dplyr solution.

Comment: Sorry I don't think it's possible to specify _or_ in the _by_  arg.

Comment: Hi @Koot6133 I repost this question into RStudio Community [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-can-i-join-two-tables-with-an-or-statement-in-r-using-dplyrs-join-functions/37633). I hope we can learn something new from them.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a sloppy way to do it in tidyverse (personally I would just use sqldf). I'm creating a `row` column which shows which row of `df2` matches, and then joining with a mutated `df2` which has a row index column.

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(row = map_int(V1, ~with(df2, which(VA == . | VB == .)))) %>% 
  left_join(mutate(df2, row = row_number()), by = 'row') %>% 
  select(-row)
#   V1 v2 VA VB vC
# 1  A  1  A  D  4
# 2  B  2  B  E  5
# 3  C  3  C  F  6
# 4  D  4  A  D  4
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old post but I came across the same issue and thought I'd take a swing at this example.  Here is an approach if you don't want to have to install `fuzzy_join`.  It depends on `tidyr` and creating an interim table to match to.

```
df1 = data.frame(V1 = c('A', 'B', 'C','D'), v2 = c(1,2,3,4))
df2 = data.frame(VA = c('A', 'B', 'C'), VB = c('D', 'E', 'F'), vC = c(4,5,6))

df2_numbered <- df2 %>%
  dplyr::mutate(row_number=dplyr::row_number())

df2_long <- df2_numbered %>%
  dplyr::select(VA,VB,row_number) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols=c("VA","VB"),
    names_to="match_key",
    values_to="match_value"
    ) %>%
  dplyr::select(-match_key) %>%
  dplyr::left_join(df2_numbered,by="row_number") %>%
  dplyr::select(-row_number)

df1 %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(df2_long,by=c("V1" = "match_value")) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(V1)


# >   V1 v2 VA VB vC
# > 1  A  1  A  D  4
# > 2  B  2  B  E  5
# > 3  C  3  C  F  6
# > 4  D  4  A  D  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that only requires `dplyr`.  You can just stitch together two joins.

```
df1 = data.frame(V1 = c('A', 'B', 'C','D'), v2 = c(1,2,3,4))
df2 = data.frame(VA = c('A', 'B', 'C'), VB = c('D', 'E', 'F'), vC = c(4,5,6))

dplyr::bind_rows(
  df1%>% 
    dplyr::mutate(match_1=V1) %>%
    dplyr::inner_join(df2 %>% dplyr::mutate(match_1=VA),by=c("match_1")) %>%
    dplyr::select(-match_1),
  df1 %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(match_2=V1) %>%
    dplyr::inner_join(df2 %>% dplyr::mutate(match_2=VB),by=c("match_2")) %>%
    dplyr::select(-match_2)
) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(V1)

#     V1 v2 VA VB vC
# > 1  A  1  A  D  4
# > 2  B  2  B  E  5
# > 3  C  3  C  F  6
# > 4  D  4  A  D  4
```

Comment: @akrun I think this is more or less equivalent to what you proposed in a comment of doing two joins and then combining them.  I'm just using `dplyr::bind_rows` instead of a `map` function from `purrr`.  And unfortunately you have to do it manually since the syntax you propose in your other comment as potentially sensible syntax: `df1 %>% full_join(df2, by = c('V1' = 'VA', 'V1' = 'VB'))` isn't actually supported.  It produces an error `Error: Join columns must be unique.`