# r - Efficient conditional join on multiple columns

Tags: r, join, conditional-statements

I have two tables that i would like to join using multiple columns, and this is perfectly feasible using the `dplyr` join functions. The complication comes from the fact that i need to join on multiple columns and the join should be succesful if at least one column join is succesful. To demonstrate my case here is a reproducible example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  A1 = c(1,2,3,4),
  B1 = c(4,5,6,7),
  C1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d")
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  A2 = c(8,"",3,4),
  B2 = c(9,5,"",7),
  C2 = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd")
)
```

I would like to join `df1` and `df2` on columns A **or** B, meaning to keep all rows where at least df1$A = df2$A or df1$B = df2$B (please note my real dataset has 6 columns that i would like to use for the joining). The end result for the simplified example should be:

```
data.frame(
  A1 = c(2,3,4),
  A2 = c("",3,7),
  B1 = c(5,6,7),
  B2 = c(5,"", 7),
  C1 = c("b", "c", "d"),
  C2 = c("bb", "cc", "dd")
)
```

Many thanks in advance for any recommendations on how this can be done efficiently or if fast is not possible then slow solution can be accepted as well

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57525522/dplyr-join-on-column-a-or-column-b , https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-can-i-join-two-tables-with-an-or-statement-in-r-using-dplyrs-join-functions/37633

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way can be:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(A1 = as.character(A1), B1 = as.character(B1))

df1 %>% 
  bind_cols(df2) %>% 
  filter(A1 == A2 | B1 == B2) %>% 
  relocate(sort(names(.)))

#>   A1 A2 B1 B2 C1 C2
#> 1  2     5  5  b bb
#> 2  3  3  6     c cc
#> 3  4  4  7  7  d dd
```

Answer (score 4):

Not quite sure how to do this using `dplyr`, but `sqldf` could help you out:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT * 
       FROM df1
       JOIN df2 
       ON df1.A1 = df2.A2 
       OR df1.B1 = df2.B2")
```

You can add additional OR statements after this for more columns.

Comment: If v1 and v2 are the names of the columns to join in df1 and df2 respectively then one can generate an SQL statement similar to that in the answer using the following where  `fn$` enables $ substitution and `verbose=TRUE` will cause it to display the generated SQL statement. `v1 <- names(df1)[1:2];
v2 <- names(df2)[1:2];
ON <- paste(sprintf("a.%s = b.%s", v1, v2), collapse = " or ");
fn$sqldf("select * from df1 a join df2 b on $ON", verbose = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this isn't possible with a single call to a `dplyr` join function.

If you would like to use a `dplyr` join, here is a hacky workaround I created using a `purrr` map function to do a separate inner join for each of the conditions in the conditional join. Then bind them together and remove duplicate rows. It can be generalized to more columns by appending to the `key1` and `key2` vectors.

*note: first we need to modify the example data so columns to be joined have the same type. `dplyr` throws an error if you try to join incompatible column types, in this case integer and character.*

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(A1 = as.character(A1), B1 = as.character(B1))

key1 <- c('A1', 'B1')
key2 <- c('A2', 'B2')

map2_dfr(key1, key2, ~ inner_join(df1, df2, by = setNames(.y, .x), keep = TRUE)) %>%
  distinct()
```

Result:

```
  A1 B1 C1 A2 B2 C2
1  3  6  c  3    cc
2  4  7  d  4  7 dd
3  2  5  b     5 bb
```

Comment: this gives an error
Error: Can't join on `x$A1` x `y$A1` because of incompatible types.
i `x$A1` is of type <double>>.
i `y$A1` is of type <character>>.

Comment: Yes see my note in the answer. Will edit