Join by any of a set of columns with OR in dplyr
In SQL, you can join by multiple columns specified with OR. I need it to bring in new columns from a lookup, where there are multiple identifiers that might match.
For example, joining x and y by columns a and b.
x <- tibble::tribble(
  ~a,   ~b,  ~old_info,
   1,   10,     "old1",
   2,   20,     "old2",
   3,   30,     "old3",
   4,   40,     "old4",
   5,   50,     "old5"
)

y <- tibble::tribble(
  ~a,   ~b,  ~new_info,
   1,   NA,     "new1",
   2,   NA,     "new2",
  NA,   NA,     "new3",
  NA,   40,     "new4",
  NA,   50,     "new5"
)

This would be the desired output.
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>       a     b old_info new_info
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1     1    10 old1     new1    
#> 2     2    20 old2     new2    
#> 3     3    30 old3     NA      
#> 4     4    40 old4     new4    
#> 5     5    50 old5     new5    


Have you tried the sqldf package?

See also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57525522/dplyr-join-on-column-a-or-column-b

Base R:
cols <- c("a", "b")
pcoalesce <- \(lst) Reduce(\(x,y) ifelse(is.na(x), y, x), lst)

x$new_info <- y$new_info[pcoalesce(lapply(cols, \(col) match(x[[col]], y[[col]])))]

x
#       a     b old_info new_info
#   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>   
# 1     1    10 old1     new1    
# 2     2    20 old2     new2    
# 3     3    30 old3     NA      
# 4     4    40 old4     new4    
# 5     5    50 old5     new5   


Try
library(powerjoin)
power_left_join(x, y, by = ~ dplyr::if_else(.x$a == .y$a | .x$b == .y$b, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), 
                keep = "left")

# A tibble: 5 × 4
      a     b old_info new_info
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>   
1     1    10 old1     new1    
2     2    20 old2     new2    
3     3    30 old3     NA      
4     4    40 old4     new4    
5     5    50 old5     new5  

from here.

Maybe even two joins and a coalesce?
x %>% 
  left_join(y, by = c(a = "a")) %>% 
  left_join(y, by = c(b.x = "b")) %>% 
  mutate(new_info = coalesce(new_info.x, new_info.y)) %>% 
  select(a = a.x, b = b.x, old_info, new_info)

# A tibble: 5 × 4
      a     b old_info new_info
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>   
1     1    10 old1     new1    
2     2    20 old2     new2    
3     3    30 old3     NA      
4     4    40 old4     new4    
5     5    50 old5     new5    


This is what I've been doing but I hate how many steps are involved

a data.table approach
library(data.table)
# set to data.table format if not already
setDT(x); setDT(y)
# set keys
setkey(x, a, b)
# self join on each a/n combination from x
#  get the first value of new_info from a subset of y
x[x, newinfo := y[a == i.a | b == i.b, new_info][1], by = .EACHI][]
# Key: <a, b>
#        a     b old_info newinfo
#    <num> <num>   <char>  <char>
# 1:     1    10     old1    new1
# 2:     2    20     old2    new2
# 3:     3    30     old3    <NA>
# 4:     4    40     old4    new4
# 5:     5    50     old5    new5


This is what worked for my needs.
Joining function
multi_left_join <- function(x, y, by, cols_y,
                            na_matches = "never", relationship = NULL) {

  # Joins -------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  # Get columns to join by as symbols (needed for tidyeval stuff)
  by_syms <- x |> 
    select({{by}}) |> 
    names() |> 
    rlang::syms()
  
  # Loop to join by each column
  for (i in seq_along(by_syms)) {
    by_sym <- by_syms[[i]]
    
    x <- x |> 
      left_join(y |>
                  select({{by_sym}}, {{cols_y}}) |> 
                  rename_with(~ paste0(., "_", by_sym), .cols = -{{by_sym}}),
                by = join_by({{by_sym}}),
                na_matches = na_matches,
                relationship = relationship)
  }
  

  # Coalesce joined columns -------------------------------------------------
  
  # We now have multiple versions of each column (with a suffix of _{{by}}).
  # This will coalesce each of those into one column, without the suffix
  
  # Get columns names as symbols (needed for tidyeval stuff)
  cols_y_syms <- y |> 
    select({{cols_y}}) |> 
    names() |> 
    rlang::syms()
  
  # Loop over each of the new columns
  for (i in seq_along(cols_y_syms)) {
    col_y_sym <- cols_y_syms[[i]]
    
    # List of symbols of each of the versions of the new column
    col_y_versions <- by_syms |> 
      map_chr(~ paste0(col_y_sym, "_", .)) |> 
      rlang::syms()
    
    # Coalesce the multiple versions. .keep = "unused" is to throw away the
    # different versions after we're done. I'd prefer to do it more explicitly
    # in select(), but I couldn't figure out the tidyeval
    x <- x |> 
      mutate({{col_y_sym}} := coalesce(!!!col_y_versions), .keep = "unused")
  }
  
  return(x)
}

Example
x <- tibble::tribble(
  ~a,   ~b,  ~old_info,
   1,   10,     "old1",
   2,   20,     "old2",
   3,   30,     "old3",
   4,   40,     "old4",
   5,   50,     "old5"
)


y <- tibble::tribble(
  ~a,   ~b,  ~new_info,
   1,   NA,     "new1",
   2,   NA,     "new2",
  NA,   NA,     "new3",
  NA,   40,     "new4",
  NA,   50,     "new5"
)



x |> 
  multi_left_join(y,
                  by = c(a, b),
                  cols_y = new_info)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>       a     b old_info new_info
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1     1    10 old1     new1    
#> 2     2    20 old2     new2    
#> 3     3    30 old3     NA      
#> 4     4    40 old4     new4    
#> 5     5    50 old5     new5    


An option could be to convert your dataframes to a longer format and remove the NA rows from your y table. After that join them by the values created column. Next, convert it back to wider format and group the rows with NA values to single rows like this:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = a:b) %>%
  left_join(y %>%
              pivot_longer(cols = a:b) %>%
              na.omit(), by = "value") %>%
  select(-name.y) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name.x, values_from = value) %>%
  group_by(old_info) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), ~ first(na.omit(.))))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   old_info new_info     a     b
#>   <chr>    <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 old1     new1         1    10
#> 2 old2     new2         2    20
#> 3 old3     <NA>         3    30
#> 4 old4     new4         4    40
#> 5 old5     new5         5    50

Created on 2024-05-16 with reprex v2.1.0

Here's a purrr::map over keys approach:
library(tidyverse) # purrr, tidyr, 

keys <- c("a", "b")
z    <- map_dfr(keys, \(i) inner_join(x, select(y, -all_of(keys[keys != i]))))
z    <- left_join(x, z)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(a, b, old_info)`

The output:
> z
# A tibble: 5 × 4
      a     b old_info new_info
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>   
1     1    10 old1     new1    
2     2    20 old2     new2    
3     3    30 old3     NA      
4     4    40 old4     new4    
5     5    50 old5     new5  

Created on 2024-05-20 with reprex v2.1.0
